# Deleting Album from MediaStore?

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to figure out how I can delete an Album from the MediaStore.

I have successfully set up deleting a single and multiple songs from the MediaStore and now would like to know how I can delete Albums from it?

If someone could help me out that would be great.

**EDIT**

Here's what I have come up with now, but I am getting a crash:

```
   public static void deleteAlbum(ContentResolver resolver, long id)
{
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
    resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

And here's the crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL: content://media/external/audio/albums/48
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:169)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:519)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1006)
        at com.test.test.test.test.Helpers.deleteAlbum(Helpers.java:48)
        at com.test.test.test.test.FragmentAlbums$deleteAlbum.doInBackground(FragmentAlbums.java:796)
        at com.test.test.test.test.FragmentAlbums$deleteAlbum.doInBackground(FragmentAlbums.java:775)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: does not `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` have content Uri to use?

Comment: Yes it does, I have set up some code now but I am getting a crash, I would post an edit...

Comment: if 48 is a valid album ID then it seems that `delete` is not supported for that Uri, only `query` imho

Comment: Would you know of any other way to delete the album? I have seen some other music apps do it.

Comment: i have a similar problem. i cant update the albums table

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    public void deleteAlbum(Context context, int _id) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + " = " + _id, null);
}
```

Comment: In general, deleting from the mediastore is pointless if you do not also delete the actual media on the sdcard. If you do not do this, a media scan will update the media database and add the album again. My New Playlist Manager has code to delete from sdcard. For removing albums, I simply delete all tracks on that album.

Answer (score 1):

I have further researched this and have resolved the issue. The following works. However, make sure you actually delete the album on the sdcard too. See previous comment

```
    public void deleteAlbum(Context context, int _id) {

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    resolver.delete(uri, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID + " = " + _id, null);
}
```